# Java 8 Function - "wrapper" function that does something before executing given lambda?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

We have the following scenario:

Mid-test, some context variables need to be updated. Where exactly in the test and what exactly should happen is variable. I would like to provide a "wrapper" function, which sets up some context variables and then performs all assertions that were given to it in the function call.

So, something like the following:

```
public void withDefaultContextA(Function<???, Void> noArgsCall) {

    setupDefaultContextA();
    noArgsCall.invoke() // not sure how apply() would be invoked here
}
```

or:

```
public void withContextA(BiFunction<???, Context, Void> providedContextCall) {

    setupContext(providedContext); // not sure how apply() would be invoked here
}
```

And in the corresponding test, these should be invoked as follows:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {

    withDefaultContextA(() -> {
        ... // do some asserts
    }

    withContext((new Context(...)) -> {
        ... // do some asserts
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Can Java 8 Functions be used in this manner? If not, is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: What about using `Consumer<Context>`? a void method which accepts as the only argument a `Context`

Comment: Agree with Lino, `Function` returns a value. Seems like `Consumer` and `BiConsumer` are a better fit for this use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you want to *decorate* any given `Runnable` (you use `Function` and `BiFunction` in your question, but as they return `Void` and seem to receive no arguments, using `Runnable` seems more appropriate here).

You can do it this way:

```
public static void withDefaultContext(Runnable original) {
    setupDefaultContextA();
    original.run();
}
```

Then, you could use the above method as follows:

```
withDefaultContext(() -> {
    // do some asserts
});
```

Or with a specific context:

```
public static void withContext(Context context, Runnable original) {
    setupContext(context);
    original.run();
}
```

Usage:

```
withContext(new Context(...), () -> {
    // do some asserts
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I couldn't think of the word *decorator*. Might've led to a more fruitful Google search. :) Thanks!